# Git Repositories in Git perspective on Eclipse does not show anymore id

Tags: eclipse, branch, egit

on Ecplise on git perspective, the Git Repositories does not show anymore the commit id.

Probably something goes wrong but before I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuIZr.png) situation.

While now the situation is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u04Fw.png).

How can I restore the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Eclipse 2021-12 including EGit 6.0. Which EGit version do you have and can you reproduce it with a fresh workspace?

Comment: I use EGIT 6.0.0 but the answer of frank below resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you unchecked the Button to "Display Latest Branch Commit".
[image]